# Any way to run R Shiny on a headless Linux server?

Tags: r, linux, png, x11, rhel7

Is there any way to run an R Shiny app on a headless Linux server (RHEL7 and R 3.3.2)? (I'm not a server admin)

Errors:

```
Listening on http://xxx.x.x.x:xxxx
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://xxx.x.x.x:xxxx'”
```

And

```
Warning in pngfun(filename = filename, width = width, height = height, res = 
res,  :
unable to open connection to X11 display ''
Warning: Error in .External2: unable to start device PNG
```

If it helps, here are my R instance capabilities:

```
   jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua
   TRUE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE

   http/ftp    sockets     libxml      fifo        cledit      iconv
   TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE

    NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU    long.double     libcurl
   TRUE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```

Comment: Yes, login with `ssh -X` with a working x11 server on your machine.

Comment: Emacs has `*-nox` packages; for example `emacs-nox` and `emacs-nox11`. Maybe you can install something similar.

Comment: @Ipor Sircer, I am actually logging in via Putty with an SSH connection. No luck.

Comment: @jww thanks. Unfortunately I am not free to install packages on the server. There is an extensive approval process...

Comment: Then try vnc, or install X server to your machine.

Comment: @Ipor Sircer, both great solutions, but my hands are tied. I cannot download any software to go either of those routes...

Comment: Then ask your sysadmin to help your work.